# Proving a vector space property

Tags: matrices

Let $M$ be a $4\times4$ matrix and $S$ be the vector space consisting of vectors of the form $MAx$ where $x\in ℝ^4$ and $A$ is a $4\times4$ matrix having a rank of $2$. Show that if $M$ is non singular then the dimension of $S$ is 2.

$$S=MAx$$
$$M^{-1}S=Ax$$ 
$M^{-1}$ exist since it is non-singular.

Can somebody complete this proof?

Moreover what's meant by "dimension" of $S$? The dimension of range space of $S$ or the dimension of null space of $S$?

Comment: Hint: What does it mean that $A$ is of rank 2?

Comment: Since "A is a 4 by 4 matrix having a rank of 2", A maps $R^4$ to a two dimensional subspace of $R^4$.  Since "M is non-singular", M maps that two dimensional subspace of $R^4$ to a two dimensional subspace of $R^4$.

Comment: @Nick it means $Ax=pe_1+qe_2$ where $p$ and $q$ are scalar. The problem I am having is, it's evident that $M^{-1}S$ has a dimension of 2, but how to make a statement for $S$?

Comment: @user247327 How do you know that M maps 2D subspace to 2D subspace? Can it not it to 1D subspace?

Comment: As you yourself pointed out, M is non-singular, so no, it cannot go down a dimension.

Comment: @Nick Can you please state the relationship between mapping dimension and determinant?

Comment: non-zero determinant implies invertible implies 1-1 and onto.

Comment: And what about 0 determinant matrices? What are their mapping criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Null space of $S$ is of dimension $2$, as a vector of the form $MAx$ is zero iff $Ax=0$ as $M$ is nonsingular, and the dimension of the vector space consisting of all vectors such that $Ax=0$ is $2$, as rank of $A$ is $2$, hence $dim(S)=4-2=2$.